# How to reference Keyvault Secret Tags from ARM template

Tags: azure, tags, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

I have an ARM template which syncs secret value from source Keyvault into Destination one.

I also want to sync secret tags, but ARM reference that I use for 'sourceKV.secret.tags' retrieval does not work

`[reference(resourceId('subscriptionId', 'resourceGroup', 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', 'SourceKV', 'Secret'), '2021-04-01-preview', 'Full').tags.tagName]`

any ideas what can be the issue, or what is the correct form to retrieve tags during ARM template deployment?

Answer (score 1):

These work for me:

```json
"outputs": {
  "tags": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[reference('/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/yyyy/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/zzzz/secrets/mysecret', '2022-07-01', 'Full').tags]"
  },
  "tagValue": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[reference('/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/yyyy/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/zzzz/secrets/mysecret', '2022-07-01', 'Full').tags.hello]"
  },
  "tagValue2": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[reference(resourceId(subscription().subscriptionId, resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets', 'xxxx', 'mysecret'), '2021-04-01-preview', 'Full').tags.hello]"
  }
}
```

Will result in:

```json
"outputs": {
  "tagValue": {
    "type": "String",
    "value": "world"
  },
  "tagValue2": {
    "type": "String",
    "value": "world"
  },
  "tags": {
    "type": "Object",
    "value": {
      "hello": "world"
    }
  }
}
```

Also works with the API version you used. It is important that you use `'Full'`, otherwise you won't get the tags. Note that you can use this syntax anywhere in your template. I just used it in the outputs because it is good for testing.

Answer (score -1):

As I found out it is not possible to use Reference function for setting tags property value for keyvault as [valid usages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#valid-uses-1) state
reference func only works if it is used inside properties block or for outputs; but as [tags are not part of properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/secrets?tabs=json#template-format) instead of returning value reference fun returns just string "reference(resource...)"